# more efficient cpp code

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to solve a problem from the site open.kattis.com https://open.kattis.com/problems/different

the problem is you take in two non-negative integers from 0 to 10^15 and you calculate the difference. I wrote this and it calculates it correctly, but it is not fast enough, how can I make it faster?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long int a, b;
    while(a != 0){
        cin >> a >> b;
        if (a > b) { cout << a-b << endl;}
        else{ cout << b-a << endl;}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a` is uninitialized.

Comment: instead of checking condition, use can use "abs(a-b)"

Comment: Getting rid of `endl` would probably help. Use `"\n"` instead.

Comment: <iostream> is notoriously heavyweight. The fastest approach would probably be to use read() to bypass all the overhead of <iostream> or <stdio.h> and then parse the string yourself to extract the integers (e.g., using a char* p and isdigit(), though you can probably get pretty good performance using strtol).

Comment: @Waxrat: Or maybe use [`sync_with_stdio(false);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio).

Answer (score 2):

The real performance hit, if ran many many times would come from the 'endl' actually, because while it adds a '\n' at the end, it also flushes the stream. Any other micro optimization is quite meaningless at best, I'm sure the compiler is smart enough to put a fast enough code in it's place.

EDIT: Could also add `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` if you are REALLY desperate for potential performance increase. This prevents the synchronization between C style streams. See: [sync](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing a comparison to see which is bigger, which takes more time, you could just forget about which is bigger and calculate the difference anyway: `cout << a-b << ends;` If `b` is larger than `a` then yes you will end up with a negative result. In which case, multiply it by -1. I work mainly in C but I think in C++, it would look something like this: first store the result of the calculation in a variable 'x' `long long int x = a-b`, then `if (x < 0) { x *= -1 ;}`. This should work if my code is correct; I'm not sure if it will be much faster but it's definitely worth a try.

EDIT: Or, like @user64322 said, you could do the same as above, but rather than multiplying by -1, just take the absolute value, which is the same, but quicker.

Comment: I bet this is totally overshadowed by the flush `endl` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the others' suggestions, an obvious thing you can do is use `argv` to take command line arguments at startup (e.g. `./PrintDiffQuick 10 5` would print `5`) instead of blocking execution while waiting for user input.

```cpp
#include <cinttypes>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
        std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
        std::cout << std::imaxabs(std::strtoimax(argv[1], nullptr, 10) -
                                  std::strtoimax(argv[2], nullptr, 10)) << '\n';
        return 0;
}
```